# Django: continuing code execution after transaction.atomic's Exception

Tags: python, django, database, atomic

Probably it's a very stupid question, but the part I am working on is so    important, so I'd like to check things twice)

Quote from [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) about `with transaction.atomic():`

> Atomicity is the defining property of database transactions. atomic
>   allows us to create a block of code within which the atomicity on the
>   database is guaranteed. If the block of code is successfully
>   completed, the changes are committed to the database. If there is an
>   exception, the changes are rolled back. **My Guess: And the following code will not be executed, because a regular python Exception raised, right?**

For example:

```
def my_view(request):

    with transaction.atomic():
        # bunch of queries

    api_call()

    return JsonResponse('Done')
```

Is there a guarantee that `api_call()` will not be executed if database Exception occur inside `transaction.atomic()` block? Big thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right. This isn't Django-specific: a database exception is a kind of `Exception`, and if an `Exception` is raised in Python (and isn't caught) the subsequent code won't be executed.